# 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check if a user is following another user. If they are then the `follow_btn` is invisible, if not then it's visible. But I keep getting this error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`.

I have called the function is different methods but I keep getting that error. I also check if the button was null in an if statement and I'm being told it's null. I don't know what else to do can someone help me ?

layout_main.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/follow_btn"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_profile"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_profile"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_profile"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
```

PostAdapter.Java:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context mContext;
public List<Post> mPost;

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
public static String mGroupId;
public String profileid;
public ImageView follow_btn;

public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPost = mPost;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_main, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    if (follow_btn != null) {

        checkFollow();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // creating a variable for exoplayerview.
    public PlayerView post_video;
    // creating a variable for exoplayer
    public SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    public ImageView image_profile, like, comment, save, follow_btn; //more
    //public ExoVideoView post_video;
    public TextView username, description, comments, dateAdded, likes;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        post_video = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
        dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_post_added);
        save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        //more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.more);

        follow_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow_btn);
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        profileid = prefs.getString("profileid", "none");
    }
}

    private void checkFollow() {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.child(profileid).exists()) {
                //.setText("following");
                follow_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                //edit_profile.setText("follow");
                follow_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `public ImageView follow_btn;` why do you have two of these ? it might solve your issue to get rid of the one as you're probably only setting an instance to the one and not the other, at the very least, it's also confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass ViewHolder in argument:-

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (follow_btn != null) {
            checkFollow(viewHolder);
        } else {
    
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



private void checkFollow(ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.child(profileid).exists()) {
                //.setText("following");
                viewHolder.follow_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                //edit_profile.setText("follow");
                viewHolder.follow_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

remove your `public ImageView follow_btn;` from top declaration. (above your constructor).

inside `onBindViewHolder` you can use childViews with it's `ViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    if (viewHolder.follow_btn != null) {

        checkFollow();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure removing the top declaration will work ? shouldn't it be the nested one that needs to be removed ?